# Naming external parameter in init method

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, arguments, naming

I have this very simple code:

```
class ESTime: NSObject {

   let hours:Int
   let minutes:Int

   init(withHours hours:Int, andMinutes minutes:Int)
   {
      self.hours   = hours
      self.minutes = minutes
   }
}
```

It doesn't compile. The error message is:

> 'with' is for the first parameter of an initialiser; did you mean to name this parameter 'hours'?

However, if I change `withHours` into anything else like `byHours` or `fromHours`it compiles ok. Why so? What's wrong with `with`?

Comment: I think this is a simple naming convention. How about `init(hours hours:Int, minutes minutes:Int)`

Comment: @freshking it produces a warning 'hours hours can be expressed more succinctly as '#hours''. If I then change hours hours to #hours it produces another warning 'extraneous # parameter; hours is already keyword argument name'

Comment: Im sorry, I meant `init(Hours hours:Int, Minutes minutes:Int)`